# $1+e^{\sqrt{-1}5t}$ form change

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have a question.

I am concerning if $1+e^{\sqrt{-1}5t}$  is exponential form or not.

If it is not exponential form, how to change it into exponential form?

I mean, exponential form is like $$x(t) = |x(t)|e^{\sqrt{-1}\theta}$$

I tried a lot but I'm not sure.

$$1+e^{\sqrt{-1}5t}= 1+\cos5t+\sqrt{-1}\sin 5t$$
So I changed it
$$\sqrt{2\cos 5t+2} e^{\sqrt{-1}\arctan(\tan(5/2)t)}$$

Is this right?

Comment: Tes, both forms are right.